# MVC Scaffolding: Compatible with nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Is the core mvc scaffolding stack something that can sit on top of my nhibernate objects, or can it only sit on EF?

Comment: [This illustration](http://i2.asp.net/media/4435069/addscaffoldoptions.png?cdn_id=2014-07-01-001) shows some of the scaffolding options.  Did you try any of the others that don't use EF?  See also [here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview).

Comment: @RobertHarvey We are primarily interested in scaffolding on top of nhibernate. EF is something we might consider. Other ORMs.... not open to it...

Comment: Did you try any of the other options in the scaffolding dialog that do not mention EF?